# MS Exchange server cloud, getting all items in a different

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I am trying to figure out how to access all items from a 'room' account.
Is it possible to somehow access the data from the room when that user isn't a real user?

I can get all rooms but the question is how to query the finditems using the room account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to authenticate as some user with a Mailbox and then grant that user access to the Room's Calendar (or the whole mailbox using Add-MailboxPermissions) or make it a delegate. Then you can just use the FolderId overload to specify you want to query that Room's Calendar folder eg

```
        FolderId RoomMailboxCalendarFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, "room@domain.com");
        CalendarView cvCalView = new CalendarView(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(31));
        FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments = service.FindAppointments(RoomMailboxCalendarFolderId, cvCalView);
```

Cheers
Glen